# Safari doesn’t detect my extension certificate [MAC]

Tags: safari, certificate, safari-extension

I have registered for the Safari Development Program and have a valid Apple ID. I've followed all the steps given by Apple.
I have the Safari Extension Certificate (the .cer file) but when I open Safari's Extension Builder, my certificate does not appear there.

I need Reputation for upload image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de formateara mi mac algo evidentemente cambio. revoque mi certificado e hice uno nuevo. no tuve problemas.

After formatting my mac something obviously change. Revoke my certificate and made a new one. I had no problems.